# How to solve org.hibernate.MappingException which is causing due to inheriting a class

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, annotations, mapping

Recently I migrate my project from Hibernate version 3.1 to 4.3 and for better performance I am trying to use annotations instead of my  xml mapping.I have the following exception in all the entity class where I am inheriting a class.The error is " org.hibernate.MappingException"

I tried to add targetEntity to the manytoOne class and added @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY) nothing worked. Changing to field annotation is not possible as I have 150+ entity class. I tried to remove the extended class, and its @override methods and the exception was not there, however, I need to add use it.

This is my entity class

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "mapusergroups", catalog = "designdb")
    public class Mapusergroups extends PlanroomMigrationEntity implements 
    java.io.Serializable {

private int idMapUserGroups;
private Groups groups;
private Users users;

public Mapusergroups() {
}

public Mapusergroups(Groups groups, Users users) {
    this.groups = groups;
    this.users = users;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

@Column(name = "idMapUserGroups", unique = true, nullable = false)
public int getIdMapUserGroups() {
    return this.idMapUserGroups;
}

public String getIdMapUserGroupsString() {
    return "" + this.idMapUserGroups;
}

public void setIdMapUserGroups(int idMapUserGroups) {
    this.idMapUserGroups = idMapUserGroups;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Groups.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "FK_idGroups", nullable = false)
@PlanroomMigrationEntity.PathUpToCompany
public Groups getGroups() {
    return this.groups;
}

public void setGroups(Groups groups) {
    this.groups = groups;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Users.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "FK_idUsers", nullable = false)
@PlanroomMigrationEntity.ReferenceToUser
public Users getUsers() {
    return this.users;
}

public void setUsers(Users users) {
    this.users = users;
}

@Override
public BaseWrapper<?> getWrapper() {
    return new WMapUserGroups(this);
}

@Override
public PlanroomMigrationDAO getDao() {
    return new MapUserGroupsDAO();
}

@Override
public void attachReferences(JSONObject json, ObjectFinder finder)
        throws JSONException {      this.users = json.has("userId") ? (Users) finder.lookup(Users.class,
json.get("userId").toString()) : null;
this.groups = json.has("groupId") ? (Groups) finder.lookup(
        Groups.class, json.get("groupId").toString()) : null;
}
```

This is my xml which Is used to convert to annotation

```
   @XmlType
   public class Mapusergroups extends PlanroomMigrationEntity implements
    java.io.Serializable {

private int idMapUserGroups;
private Users users;
private Groups groups;

public Mapusergroups() {
}

@Deprecated
public Mapusergroups(Users users, Groups groups) {
    this.users = users;
    this.groups = groups;
}

@XmlAttribute
public int getIdMapUserGroups() {
    return this.idMapUserGroups;
}

@XmlAttribute
@XmlID
public String getIdMapUserGroupsString() {
    return "" + this.idMapUserGroups;
}

public void setIdMapUserGroups(int idMapUserGroups) {
    this.idMapUserGroups = idMapUserGroups;
}

@XmlAttribute
@XmlIDREF
@PlanroomMigrationEntity.ReferenceToUser
public Users getUsers() {
    return this.users;
}

public void setUsers(Users users) {
    this.users = users;
}

@XmlAttribute
@XmlIDREF
@PlanroomMigrationEntity.PathUpToCompany
public Groups getGroups() {
    return this.groups;
}

public void setGroups(Groups groups) {
    this.groups = groups;
}

@Override
public BaseWrapper<?> getWrapper() {
    return new WMapUserGroups(this);
}

@Override
public PlanroomMigrationDAO getDao() {
    return new MapUserGroupsDAO();
}

@Override
public void attachReferences(JSONObject json, ObjectFinder finder)
        throws JSONException {
    this.users = json.has("userId") ? (Users) finder.lookup(Users.class,
            json.get("userId").toString()) : null;
    this.groups = json.has("groupId") ? (Groups) finder.lookup(
            Groups.class, json.get("groupId").toString()) : null;
}
```

I need to use PlanroomMigrationEntity with property annotation. Please help.

This is my stacktrace

> > org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.at.project.service.planroom_migration.PlanroomMigrationDAO, at
> >     table: mapusergroups, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(dao)]
> >       at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:349)
> >       at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:322)
> >       at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:241)    at
> >     org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:496)
> >       at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)     at
> >     org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1360)     at
> >     org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1851)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
> >       at wadetech.DB.base.HibernateUtils.(HibernateUtils.java:111)
> >       at wadetech.DB.base.BaseDAO.(BaseDAO.java:43)     at
> >     wadetech.DB.DAOS.__MaintenanceDAO.(__MaintenanceDAO.java:10)    at
> >     com.at.project.utils.runtime.RuntimeModifier.HasExecuted(RuntimeModifier.java:127)
> >       at
> >     wadetech.listeners.ModificationScriptStartupListener.contextInitialized(ModificationScriptStartupListener.java:47)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
> >       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
> >     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
> >       at
> >     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
> >       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have much to do with inheritance. Read the error message. It says the Hibernate doesn't know how to map the property `dao` of type `PlanroomMigrationDAO` of your entity.

This property shouldn't exist in the first place: an entity shouldn't be in charge of creating DAOs.

But if you really want to stick with that design, you need to tell JPA that dao is not a persistent property. That's the role of the `@Transient` annotation.

Comment: Thank you, Got your point there. It saved me from that exception. I am learning more about it and this point there is no other choice for me other than using the dao there. I am working on a scratch, and I have to convert XML to annotation. Entity class was with dao in the old code. Can you please suggest the best practice for using dao in this context, for my later work. Thank you.

Comment: Use Spring Data JPA, use dependency injection to inject your repositories in services which need them.

Comment: Thank you for the response.I am a beginner and I have to give a good dive in that and I will do it.Thank you so much for your suggestion.

Comment: I have a shallowclone() method in one of the enity class.I need to make tham @transient as well right? I had serialization issue so when I worked with xml wecreate shallowclone methods in this enity class.Any word on this will be greatful sir.Thank you.